# Point $G_1$ represents the centroid of $\triangle ABD$ and point $G_2$ represents the centroid of $\triangle ABC$ in the trapezoid $ABCD$ $(AB||CD)$

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry

> Point $G_1$ represents the centroid of $\triangle ABD$ and point $G_2$ represents the centroid of $\triangle ABC$ in the trapezoid $ABCD$ $(AB||CD)$. Show $G_1G_2 \parallel AB \parallel CD$ and find $G_1G_2$ if $CD=a$ $cm$.

[image]

$G_1$ is the centroid of $\triangle ABD$ iff $\vec{G_1A}+\vec{G_1B}+\vec{G_1D}=\vec{0}$, but this does not help here. I am trying to show $\vec{G_1G_2}=\dfrac{1}{3}\vec{DC}$. Can someone help me?

Comment: I have a geometric method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you wanted to see how to do it with vectors, The centroid of the triangle with vertices $\vec u, \vec v, \vec w$ is given by their average: $\frac 13(\vec u + \vec v + \vec w)$.
Therefore (choosing any arbitrary point as the origin, and identifying all the points with the vector from the origin to it): $$G_1 = \frac{(A + B + C)}3,\quad G_2 = \frac{(A + B + D)}3$$
And therefore $$\vec{G_1G_2} = G_2 - G_1 = \frac D3 - \frac C3 = \frac13(D - C) = \frac13\vec{CD}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$.

$\vec{G_1G_2}=\vec{G_1D}+\vec{DC}+\vec{CG_2}=\dfrac{2}{3}\vec{MD}+\vec{DC}+\dfrac{2}{3}\vec{CM}=\dfrac{2}{3}(\vec{MD}+\vec{CM}) + \vec{DC}=\dfrac{2}{3}(\vec{MD}-\vec{MC})+\vec{DC}=\dfrac{2}{3}\vec{CD}+\vec{DC}=\vec{DC}-\dfrac{2}{3}\vec{DC}=\dfrac{1}{3}\vec{DC}$

$\Rightarrow G_1G_2 || AB || CD$ and $G_1G_2=\dfrac{1}{3}CD$

Comment: What is $M$? And why is $\vec{G_1D} = \frac23\vec{MD}$ and $\vec{CG_2} = \frac23\vec{CM}$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair, $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$. $\vec{G_1D}=\frac{2}{3}\vec{MD}$, because $G_1D=\frac{2}{3}MD$ and they lie on the same line.

Comment: My point is that this information has to be part of your solution. Your solution is wrong without it. And how do you know that $G_1D = \frac 23 MD$ and $G_1, M$ and $D$ are colinear? If this has already been proven, then you need to explicitly reference that. If it hasn't, then the proof needs to be part of your solution as well.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, that's obvious. $G_1$ represents the centroid of $\triangle ABD$; thus, $G_1$ lies on every median. $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$, so $DM$ is a median and $DG_1=\frac{2}{3}DM$ (the centroid divides the length of each median in $2:1$ ratio).

Comment: How do you know that the centroid lies on every median? How do you know that that the centroid divides the length of each median in a 2:1 ratio? If you drew a picture of this and showed it to someone intelligent but who has not studied the geometry of triangles in any depth, would they agree that these two things are "obvious"? As a rule of thumb, anything that you cannot prove in 5 lines no wider than your hand does not qualify as "obvious".

Comment: @PaulSinclair, where the medians intersect is the centroid. The centroid divides each median into two parts, which are always in the ratio $2:1$. This is a fundamental basic property of centroids. I'll stop here. You may want to read this article - https://brilliant.org/wiki/triangles-centroid/.

Comment: You've completely missed my point. I am not trying to figure out why you think they are true. if you look at my post, the formula I gave also quickly proves it. What I am trying to get you to understand is that *this information needs to be included in your solution*. When you write out mathematics, you need to be aware of your audience, not just yourself. You have been studying this closely. The people you are trying to communicate it to have not. Even those who are aware of these results may not have them at the top of their mind. It is your job to remind them.

Comment: Figure out your audience is. Then subtract off a *minimum* of 1 year from your estimate of the lowest education level among them. Your job is to persuade them that the theorem is true. So you need to explain it to them carefully and clearly. Any time you make use of a result beyond basic mathematics that *everyone* knows, you should make explicit reference of that result. This is why I stated that the centroid is the average of the vertices before I made use of it. I didn't just assume you would know (in fact, from your remarks in the OP, I doubted that you knew).

Comment: @PaulSinclair, I understand what you're saying. I didn't get your solution because I have only studied vectors determined by two points. I have an elementary knowledge of vectors. I know that the equality $\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}=3\vec{OG}$ is true for every point $O$ if we have $\triangle ABC$ with centroid $G$. Why don't you use vectors in expressing $G_1$ and $G_2$? Shouldn't we write $\vec{G_2}=\dfrac{\vec{A} + \vec{B} + \vec{C}}{3}$?

Comment: Or $G_2 = \dfrac{(A + B + C)}3$?

Comment: There are many notations for vectors. You will find that almost universally, when mathematicians talk about vectors, there is a particular point designated as the origin, and all vectors eminate from it. This identifies vectors with points and allows you to treat them identically. You will also discover that denoting vectors wth a $\to$ on top is something that is rarely done after the 2nd year in college, Denoting them by boldface (for example, $\mathbf v$) tends to fade out as a common practice soon after. Basically, I overestimated your exposure to vectors, partly out of laziness.

Comment: I admit I mixed up your definitions of $G_1$ and $G_2$, so it should have been $$G_1 = \frac {A + B + D}3\\G_2 = \frac {A+B+C}3$$ You can interpret this as $$\vec{OG_1} = \frac {\vec{OA} + \vec{OB} + \vec{OD}}3\\\vec{OG_2} = \frac {\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}}3$$as you wish.